# concatenating sass files with saving correct paths for images urls and for sass @imports

Tags: gulp

I have some scss files in different folders. I want to concatenate them into one file main.scss and to compile this main.scss. I used gulp-concat for this, but using this plugin I get wrong images URL paths in main.scss and wrong sass @imports paths.

Maybe somebody knows plugin for concatenating files with saving correct paths for images URLs and for sass @imports?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't concatenate SASS/SCSS files before compilation. Use `@import` SASS directive instead. More information [here](http://sass-lang.com/guide#import).